# Server locks up while streaming video suspect hardware failure

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, video, samba

Config is as follows:

Core 2 Duo E6750
P5G41T-M Motherboard (Intel 535 (sda) Seagate 888GB (sdb))
IBM M1015 HBA (2-2TB WD RED, 2-4TB WD RED)

Was watching a video the other night with VLC through Samba and it froze, quickly switched over to glances (ncurses based system monitor) and its giving me load warnings think the load was above 2 for about 5 minutes. Video files in question are located on Seagate drive. Never has happened to me before but has happened about 5 times now kind of randomly. Checking the logs only leads to more questions.

[Syslog.1](http://pastebin.com/40kt6eq9)

Then about half hour later my samba streaming video froze again this time with cpuiowait errors.

[Syslog.2](http://pastebin.com/QGPmQGCA)

Trying to find out what ata3.00 and 3.01 are (due to formatting issues with this site I'm just going to pastebin):

pastebin.com/HNVB4cja

Am I to assume that unique id 3 (ata3) is host2 which is sda and sdb or am I doing it wrong? If it is a hardware failure I can see it being the Seagate, it has a really high reallocated sector count and has for quite some time but the Intel ssd is brand new and I can't see that crapping out already. Could it be a motherboard issue since it seems to only be affecting the drives hooked to the MB? Although...

Output of dmesg | grep ata
pastebin.com/bfheLQTB

Since this seems to be an intermittent issue that I wouldn't even have noticed had samba streamed videos not started freezing I'm not sure what the problem is. If the error linked directly to one drive I could pin it down but it seems to link to two drives leading me to think motherboard anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some type of resource threshold.  that your browser will reach.  I just did a top to get the Process ID for your browser and renice it to -1.  Once I did that it stopped locking.  If your PID was 18737 type

sudo renice -n -1 -p 18737

I haven't had time to figure out how to modify user thresholds, but I am sure it is an easy setting somewhere.  else you have to do this every time you reboot.